# write call to usb drive in C always returning -1 in MAC OS

Tags: c, macos

I am trying to do a write operation on to a USB drive in MAC OS. However, when I open the device in O_RDWR mode, file descriptor is returning a large value and write call fails with -1.

```
uint64_t fd = open("/dev/disk2", O_RDWR);
ssize_t writeData = write(fd, buffer, 1024);
```

Can anyone please suggest how to fix this in MAC OS?
This works fine in LINUX OS.

Comment: `man 2 open` says, "If successful, open() returns a non-negative integer, termed a file descriptor.  It returns -1 on failure, and sets errno to indicate the error."  So, your large number is probably -1.  (The docs also say that it returns int rather than uint.)  `man errno` should give you a list of values and meanings.

Comment: using int will fail to open the descriptor with -1. in mac it works if we use uint32_t or uint64_t. however write fails with -1

Comment: Getting (int)-1 on open() is reasonable but then you need to check `errno` for the reason.

Comment: An arbitrary write like what you're trying (but failing) to do will probably screw up the disk drive.  Be cautious about what you do.

Comment: @SashiKiran *using int will fail to open the descriptor with -1. in mac it works if we use uint32_t or uint64_t* [Not likely](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.60.75/bsd/man/man2/open.2.auto.html). Also because [`open()` is a POSIX-standard function that returns `int`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/open.html). Full stop. That comment really makes me wonder what else is going on in the code you didn't post.

Comment: To elaborate on what Andrew Henle is saying, using an unsigned for the return doesn't "work," it's just camouflaging the return value of open(). The call can't give you a negative value if you're storing the return in a uint.